# Want to display the contents of csv/xlsx files in Object

Tags: java, excel, csv

Want to display the contents of csv/xlsx files in Object.I want to display each row of the file in an Object. Below is my code. I want to create a class named Item and store the name of the columns in it.

```
    package com.pack;

import java.awt.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class Final
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

         final String extXlsx="xlsx";
         final String extCSV="csv";
        String ext = "C:\\Users\\swapnil.sanjay.saraf\\Desktop\\.xlsx";
        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(extXlsx.equals(FilenameUtils.getExtension(ext)))
        {

                String excelPath = "C:\\Users\\swapnil.sanjay.saraf\\Desktop\\ItemID.xlsx";
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));

                // Create Workbook instance holding .xls file
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

                // Get the first worksheet
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                // Iterate through each rows
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                System.out.println("\n******XLSX FILE******\n");
                while (rowIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Item item;
                    // Get Each Row
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();

                    // Iterating through Each column of Each Row
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                        // Checking the cell format
                        switch (cell.getCellType())
                        {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                    itemList.add(item);
                }
        }
                else if(extCSV.equals(FilenameUtils.getExtension(ext)))
                {

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\swapnil.sanjay.saraf\\Desktop\\KitsCP.csv"));
                scanner.useDelimiter(",");
                System.out.println("\n******CSV FILE******\n");
                while(scanner.hasNext()){
                    System.out.print(scanner.next()+"  ");

                }
                scanner.close();


        }

                else{

                    System.out.println("Inavlid Extension");
                }


}
}
```